# Android - ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, Problema para capturar imagem

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvimento uma aplicação que necessita de uma foto do usuário. Para isso, desenvolvi um código que é responsável pela captura e redimensionamento da imagem.
Este é código:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
            .format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
                    String dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/MyApplication/imagens/";
            File projDir = new File(dirPath);

            if (!projDir.exists()) {
                projDir.mkdirs();
            }
    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", projDir);
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

public void abrirCamera(Activity activity) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File imagem = null;
    try {
        imagem = createImageFile();
        if (imagem != null) {
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imagem));
            intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
            intent.putExtra("outputX", cameraConfig.getLargura());
            intent.putExtra("outputY", cameraConfig.getAltura());
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent,
                    cameraConfig.getResultCodeCamera());
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}

public Bitmap getImagemCamera() {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    if (currentPhotoPath != null) {
        ImageView imagemCamera = cameraConfig.getImageView();

        int targetW = imagemCamera.getWidth();
        int targetH = imagemCamera.getHeight();

        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);

        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        deletarArquivo(currentPhotoPath);
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Para fazer uso dessa funcionalidade, na minha activity tenho este código:

```
public void abrirCamera(ImageView imagemPerfil) {
    //cameraControler e conf são variáveis globais
    if (cameraControler == null) {
        conf = new CameraConfig(imagemPerfil, CAMERA_REQUEST_PERFIL,
                CAMERA_REQUEST_GALERIA, 512, 512);
        cameraControler = new CameraController(conf);
    }
    cameraControler.abrirCamera(this);
}
```

e no onActivityResult:

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_PERFIL) {
            SharedPreferencesManager.setCallbexEditado(this, true);
            if (cameraControler != null) {
                fragEditarDados.atualizaImagemPerfil(cameraControler
                        .getImagemCamera());
            }
        }
```

Faço debug nos aparelhos:
 1 - Galaxy Gran Prime Duos - 4.4.4
 2 - Moto G - 4.4.4
 3 - Zenfone 5 - 4.4.2
 4 - Galaxy tab 3 - 4.1.2

O meu problema se subdivide nos seguintes pontos:
 No aparelho 1 consigo fazer a captura da imagem, mas não consigo cortá-la.
 No aparelho 3 a câmera nativa do aparelho quebra.
 Nos aparelho 2 e 4 ao retornar para activity, no onActivityResult, as variáveis globais, que antes da abertura da câmera estavam todas instanciadas e valoradas, estão todas nulas, o que impossibilita o get da imagem.

Alguém já passou por algo parecido e poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Qual a versão do android de cada um? Qual a versão min a max do seu app, no manifest? Qual a versão do seu SDK?

Comment: Meu SDK é ultima versão disponível.           compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
minSdkVersion 10
targetSdkVersion 21

Comment: Qual o `launchMode` dessa Activity no `AndroidManifest`?

Comment: Está o default "standard"